# Vuejs with Ruby and Webpacker, not displaying view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js

I'm just trying to get Webpacker, Rails and Vuejs working together. I've installed everything, I'm not getting any errors in the console or in my logs. I started the Vue server and my Rails server fine. I am getting the output in the console from my Vue instance, and I can see traffic on my rails server when I reload the page. I'm missing something minor, I just can't figure out what. [You all can also enjoy my blank page by clicking on this sentence](https://new-ship-trimakas.c9users.io/)

Here is my code:

```
/app/javascript/packs/application.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../components/app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'))
  const app = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
  })

  console.log(app)
})
```

and

```
/app/javascript/components/app.vue
<template>
  <div id='app'>
      <h1>Anything?</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        message: "Welcome to My Nightmare!"
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  p {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

my `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cinematronix</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simple routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#index'
end
```

My application controller is just this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  def index
  end

end
```

And then finally the `index.html.erb` is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Vue from `vue/dist/vue.esm`

Looks like the article you used has a comment that has this suggestion for people using Rails 5.1

Comment: wow, I knew it was something minor like that... thanks so much!